# How to create a Boolean tensor from a tensor based on whether values in this other tensor is a key in a dictionary or not without using numpy?

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensor

I have a tensor of shape (N,T) with integer values and a dictionary where key and value both are integers. I want to create a Boolean tensor of the same shape i.e (N,T) where a entry is true only if the value corresponding in the input tensor is present in the dictionary.

For example, the following is my input,

```
A = [[2,3,4],
     [6,7,8]]
dictionary = {1: -1, 2: -1, 3: -1, 4: -1, 5: -1, 6: -1}
```

I want to create  a Boolean tensor such as,

```
B = [[True, True, True],
     [True, False, False]]
```

Here, each entry of B is True where the corresponding entry in A is a valid key in the dictionary. I have to do this without converting tensor to numpy, so any help would be appreciated.

PS: I am using Tensorflow v1, so please provide solution that is compatible with v1 of Tensorflow.

Answer (score 0):

As long as these are not huge tensors you can do the following,

This assumes you know the number of columns in your tensor, so that we can do the reshaping back and forth.

```
A = tf.constant([[2,3,4], [6,7,8]])

dictionary = {1: -1, 2: -1, 3: -1, 4: -1, 5: -1, 6: -1}
b = tf.constant(list(dictionary.keys()))

c = tf.map_fn(lambda x: tf.reduce_any(tf.equal(b,x)), tf.reshape(A,[-1]), dtype=bool)
c = tf.reshape(c, [-1,3])
```

`tf.map_fn` is quite slow compared to other vectorized operations in TF. Therefore, you might observe slow times if you use this on large tensors.

Also, if you use TF 2 you can achieve this with less lines of code.